# Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: "Facebook"}) in react native returns [ERROR] OAuth - Error handling auth response. [Error: invalid_client]

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, facebook-login, federated-identity

I am trying to configure a Social Sign In for Facebook in my react native mobile app using Cognito's hosted UI. My intention is to have any user that signs in with Facebook to have an enabled user in my Cognito User Pool.

However, when I click my "Login with Facebook" button and redirected to Cognito/Facebook's auth flow, it closes the embedded browser immediately and shows the following error in the logs:

`[ERROR] 19:02.561 OAuth - Error handling auth response. [Error: invalid_client]`

I have a manually configured aws backend with the following configuration:

```
export default awsConfig = {
    Auth: {
      "aws_project_region": "us-west-2",
      identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxx',
      region: 'us-east-1',
      userPoolId: 'us-east-xxxxx',
      userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxx',
      mandatorySignIn: false,
      oauth: {
        domain: "myapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
        scope: [
            "email",
            "openid",
        ],
        redirectSignIn: "myapp://",
        redirectSignOut: "myapp://",
        responseType: "code",
        urlOpener
      },
      federationTarget: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
   }
}
```

This is my Facebook Login configuration:

[image]

And here is my react native code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsConfig from './aws-custom-exports';

const configObj = Amplify.configure(awsConfig);

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    user: null,
    customState: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Hub.listen("auth", ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case "signIn":
          this.setState({ user: data });
          console.log("Sign in event recorded.")
          break;
        case "signOut":
          this.setState({ user: null });
          break;
        case "customOAuthState":
          this.setState({ customState: data });
          console.log("Custom OAuth event recorded.")
        default:
          console.log("Other auth event: ", data)
      }
    })
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(user => this.setState({ user }))
      .catch(() => console.log("Not signed in"));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
            style={styles.scrollView}>
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <Button onPress={() => {
                Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: "Facebook"})
                  .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                  })
                  .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err)
                  })
              }} title="Login with Facebook" />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  }
});

export default App;
```

My Info.plist file has the CFBundleURLSchemes set to `myapp` and have added the RTCLinking code snippets to my AppDelegate.m